# How to using two <script> 's in single View Page

Tags: javascript, html

i have write code to onload function. i also have some scritps to execute in click function. in the same script
 `window.load=alert("loaded");`
is not working but open a new

```
<script>
window.load = alert("loaded");
</script>
```

is working.

Whats wrong with the Code..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. i use

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    // code here
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <body onload="myFunction()">

  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
          alert("Page is loaded");
   }
   </script>    
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have two separate scripts within your head/body etc.

```
<script>
    /* Some code Here
</script>

<script>
/* Some code Here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  alert('loaded');
};
</script>
```